Best algorithm to perform multi pattern search on large FASTA file
I am currently working on a bioinformatics problem where I need to lookup and count the location and count of occurences of 4000-ish 6 character long patterns in a fasta file of 700GB. As a newbie to big data processing, I just came across the aho-corasick algorithm and am wondering if I can use this for my application? I need to calculate the percentage of sequences that have a particular pattern at every position of the sequence. eg - GGTTTT is found in 57/100 sequences at position 3 of the sequence. Looking for some guidance about how to proceed. Thanks!
I have not yet tried any techniques as I am new to the field of parallel processing

More details, inputs, expected outputs? The estimated total number of chars? 4000 patterns, more examples of GGTTTT? Range of chars? [A-Z]? What is your plan with aho-corasick algorithm?

This type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Thanks! I'll post on there ith more details
